# Save an edit text from an alert dialog and use it as a string variable (Kotlin)

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

I'm really new with android studio and kotlin and I'm having troubles doing an alert dialog that saves the edit text on a variable and then uses it in another activity.

To be clear I want to make an activity where there is a button. If you click on it then the Alert Dialog happens and the text should be store in a variable called "name". Code:

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    var name: String? = null
    lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        create.setOnClickListener{
                val editAlert = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
                val editView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_create, null)
                editAlert.setView(editView)
                editAlert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Accept") { _, _ ->
                    val text = editAlert.alert_dialog_create_btn.text
                    name= text.toString()
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
                editAlert.show()
            }

        }
}
```

Then, I want that name to be use as my sqlite table name. So I have mi SQLite Helper as this:

```
val DATABASE_NAME = "Test"
val COL_ID =" id"
val COL_NAME = "name"


class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(var context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1) {

    var table_name = MainActivity2().name

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

        val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + table_name +" (" +
                COL_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                COL_NAME + " VARCHAR(256))"
        db?.execSQL(createTable)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {

    }

    fun insertData(database :Database){
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        var cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_NAME, database.nombre))
        var result = db.insert(table_name, null, cv)
        if(result == -1.toLong())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And then, on another Activity, I have the edit text where the user can input the data of the table and at top of it should be an edit text with the table name (that should change if the user input a new name).

Code:

```
class Main2InsertActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2_insert)
        val context = this
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2_insert)
        val tituloView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titulo)
        tituloView.setText(AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(context).table_name)


        insertar.setOnClickListener {
            if ((name.text.toString().length > 0)
            ){
                var baseDatos = Database(name.text.toString())
                var db = AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(context)
                db.insertData(baseDatos)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Rellena todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the proble is in MainActivity2 because as much as I put a new name with button create and the alert dialog the value of name never changes, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Each `Activity` and `Fragment` (including dialogs) is a completely separate object with no connection to each other. Using the same name for a variable in two different objects is irrelevant, because they're completely unrelated.

You need to learn how to pass data between `Activity`s and the like, which is one of the trickier parts of getting your head around how Android apps work (seems to account for a lot of the questions on here too!). It's a pretty big and fundamental subject, so you'll need to learn about it yourself. Here's some links!

[Passing Events Back to the Dialog's Host](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs?hl=en#PassingEvents)

[Using Intents to pass data to Activities](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Intents-to-Create-Flows)

[Communicating with fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)

[Centralising data with ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Android's been around a while and there are a lot of ways to do this by now - and I know, there's a lot to learn. At least get familiar with passing data in `Intent`s, and the the idea of calling a method on the parent `Activity` (from the first link)

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you so much! I'm totally new with android and kotlin and it's kinda hard

Comment: Yeah I get that, passing data around the system is a bit clunky and limited (and getting around the limits takes more work), and it takes a bit of time to get your head around! Really you're not just learning Kotlin, you're learning how Android works too. In case you didn't know, there are some official tutorial courses, and this one covers Activities and Intents (including passing data from one to the other): https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-an-activity#0 good luck! You'll get there :)

Answer (score 0):

1. var table_name = MainActivity2().**name**
2. class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
3. var **name**: String? = null

I am honestly not sure how to reply. Why do you think that **name** on the 1st line and **name** on the 3d line are part of the same object? Why are you trying to instantiate on your own an Activity?

What are you trying to achieve with this project? If it  is something that you want to use for yourself and you just want to make it work and you do not want to invest time in learning Android - "this is ok".

Otherwise, if you want to make something that looks like an Android application - everything is just so far from what it should be that StackOverflow can't help. You just need to invest more time.

Why are you not using Room for the Database?

Comment: It's an exercise and they ask me to do this... It's my first time with Kotlin but as much as I know getters are autogenerated. In Java I would do something like MainActivity2 x = new MainActivity2; int table_name = x.name; but as I said, I'm totally new at kotlin and I look some tutorials and saw something like I wrote and I tried.

Comment: If you want to learn something try the courses at www.udacity.com They are great and free. But otherwise, it will be a pain to try to make it work. You just need the basics first.